# Catch randomly generated numbers and store them into array in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, data-visualization

I'm learning React and doing a practice task. I need to generate numbers every (time interval), which I did like this.

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const SalesGenerator = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  //   let salesArr = [];
  useEffect(() => {
   
    const interval = setInterval(
      () => setNumber(Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 + 1)),
      1000,
    );

    // clean up interval on unmount
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{number}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SalesGenerator;
```

How do I grab every generated number and push it into an array. I understand this is the step I need to get to in order to use the array/object to generate a chart to visualise that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(
      () => setNumber(Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 + 1)),
      1000,
    );
    // clean up interval on unmount
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setList([...list, number])
  }, [number])
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{list}</p>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, Yi Zhou. It makes a lot of sense, but somehow doesn't work. :(

Comment: My bad, you will need two useEffect in order to get working, one to track random number and one to push to list

Comment: So cool, Yi Zhou! It did not occur to me to use two useEffects and two state hooks for each element. I tried to shove it all into one useEffect. Great answer! Makes perfect sense.

Comment: seems to me like bad practice...